# How to generalize the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition to more dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiclassical

As in the title-how to consider this condition on e.g. a polar or spherical coordinate system, with two or three dimensions? 
Which different methods I can use?

EDIT: the coordinate system doesn't matter, I'm interested in the n-dimensional generalization of this condition.

Comment: Why do you think that the Bohr-Sommerfeld conditions depend on the coordinate system. Is Bohr-Sommerfeld not just saying that the action-angle variables are to be taken as discretized?

Comment: does my question imply that it should depend on the coordinate system? I'm asking for two-three dimensional cases, because everywhere only the one dimensional process is explained, and not much is said about n-dimensional generalization, the coordinate system doesn't matter

Comment: You ask *"how to consider this condition on e.g. a polar or spherical coordinate system"*, it seems to imply to me you think it depends on the coordinate system. But be that as it may, I don't see what about the discretization of the action variable $\int p\mathrm{d}q$ does not immediately generalize to the discretization of the action variables $\int p_i\mathrm{d}q_i$ in higher dimensions.